# How to get the user's country based on iTunes setting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes

I would like to get the user's country based on the settings on iTunes. Is there a file that I can read to get this data using objective-c?

Thanks

Comment: I would image that Apple stores that information on their server with your account information. I believe that information is only used to limit what items you can purchase.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the case since the iTunes store won't open without an internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you [get the current locale](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html) from the system? The [NSLocale class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides the `+systemLocale` and `+currentLocale` class methods.

Comment: I've looked at that and in some cases, the result is not the same. For instance, the user may have setup iTunes using info as a Canadian and the system settings may be US.